# WPF UI resize after minimize and restore

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a WPF Application. I need to minimize and restore the main window after instantiate it to obtain focus. I am using something like the following class but it is not making what I want because when the window is restored it has an invalid size. I've tried to modify the width and height but it is not working.

```
public class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConfigureWindow();
    }

    public void Show()
    {
        base.Show();
        UpdateWindowPositionAndSize();
        base.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
        base.Show();
    }

    private void ConfigureWindow()
    {
        base.ShowActivated = true;
        this.Focusable = true;

        if (base.IsActive == false)
        {
            base.Activate();
        }
        if (base.IsFocused == false)
        {
            base.Focus();
        }
        base.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }

    private void UpdateWindowPositionAndSize()
    {
        this.Top = (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - this.Height) / 2;
        this.Left = (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - this.Width) / 2;
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? There is another way to obtain the focus? Sorry if the question is too newby.

**UPDATED:**

*What is the specific need?*

I need that my WPF Application appears on focus and active after launch it.

*why?*

Since it will be launched by a Windows (7, 8.1 and 10) User after explicitly click on a submenu from a file context menu (meaning a Shell Extension). This is 'why' my client wants that appears on front of the screen and focused.

*when?*

After instantiate the window.

*how?*

Well, I made some research and I found several ways to do this. One of the methods that I've tried is minimize the window and the restore it. There where others like using the functions SwitchToThisWindow or setforegroundwindow, but I would like to know if there are better options.

*What happen when I've tried minimize and restore the window? (correct size)*

Well, this way gives me focus on the main window, but it change the width and heigh. By default I define them on 300 (w) and 300 (h), but after changing the windows state to normal these values change to 400 (w) and 350 (h).

*If I dont do anything, it has the focus right away?*

... No ...

**UPDATE2:**

I choose the method used in the next link:
https://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/2014/09/05/reliable-bring-external-process-window-to-foreground-without-c/

Comment: *"I need to minimize and restore the main window after instantiate it to obtain focus"* ... why ?

Comment: I know it is dirty :c, but my client want to obtain the focus after launching the app, if there is a more elegant way please let me know

Comment: Isn't `MainWindow` your main form class ?  Elaborate on what is the specific need, why, when, how ... because at least for me this is unclear. What is the issue ? ... when the form opens it has no focus ? ....

Comment: And please define what a *correct size* would be in this context

Comment: If it's the main window when the application starts, it should have focus right away (out of the box) without doing anything.

Comment: Yes, when the form opens, it has no focus ... (I've updated the post, thanks for your suggestions)

Comment: `window.Active()` should set it as the Top-Most Window (give it focus) - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.window.activate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Also setting the `TopMost` Property to `true` and then `false` should do the job..

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what your problem is but maybe this can help.

1.) Remove `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"` from `App.xaml`;

2.) Add `Startup="Application_Startup"`

Your `App.xaml.cs` should look like this:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        //Create new Instance of MainWindow
        MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();
        //Set Properties of that Window
        UpdateWindowPositionAndSize(mainWindow);

        //Show it !
        MainWindow = mainWindow; //This is the Application.MainWindow Property - not needed
        mainWindow.ShowDialog();
    }

    private void UpdateWindowPositionAndSize(MainWindow mainWindow)
    {
        //Do your modifications here
        mainWindow.Top = (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Height - mainWindow.Height) / 2;
        mainWindow.Left = (SystemParameters.WorkArea.Width - mainWindow.Width) / 2;
    }
}
```

So basically you just modify your `Window` until **all**  is done.
There is no need to show it first, change its position and then bring it back on - if I got your "usecase" right.

Because to me it looks like you are hiding the window to do your "positioning".
But I think it's better to do it when `Initializing`.

---

Just a short comment on your code so far:

`ConfigureWindow()` is only doing `minimize`.
The rest of your code is useless cause obviously the window loses focus when it's minimized.

I would suggest not to create methods with names that already exist.
[image]

This will only lead to cusfusion.

If you got problems with `WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;` you can try `Hide()` and `Activate()`.

By default when calling `Window.Show();` the window will have focus. Check here for [details](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.window.show(v=vs.110).aspx).

Also after setting `WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;` you don't need to call `base.Show();` again - the window is shown already. `WindowState = WindowState.Normal;` should do the job.